# Show that the homomorphism $\lambda: k[X] \to End_k(V) : p \mapsto p(A)$ corresponding to the $k[X]$-module strucutre of $V$ has a nontrivial kernel.

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, modules

$\DeclareMathOperator{\End}{End}$
I'm trying to show that:

> Show that the homomorphism $\lambda: k[X] \to \End_k(V) : p \mapsto p(A)$ corresponding to the $k[X]$-module strucutre of $V$ as in (see below) has a nontrivial kernel.

I've shown that:

> Let $V$ be a finite dimensional $k$-vector space and let $A \in \End_k(V)$. Show that $V$ admits a unique $k[X]$-module structure such that $X.v = A(v)$ for all $v\in V$

**This is my try:**
So we need to show that there exists a polynomial $f \neq 0$ such that $f(A) = 0$. In other words, $f(A).v$ must be $0$ for all $v\in V$. So $\sum_{i=0}^n a_i (A(v))^i$ must be $0$ where some $a_i$ are non-zero. If all $(A(v))^i$ where L.I. this would be impossible, so apperently, we need to show that $(A(v))^i$ are linear dependent and that we can choose $a_i$ so that $\sum_{i=0}^n a_i (A(v))^i=0$. How can we show this ?

Comment: You probably mean $A^i(v)$. Let $\dim V = n$. It is of course possible to prove that the $A^i(v)$ for $i=0, \dots, n$ are linearly dependent, since $V$ has dimension $n$, and there are $n+1$ vectors. However, this won't prove what you want, because in order for your polynomial $f$ to satisfy $f(A) = 0$, you'd need your $a_i$'s to be *the same* no matter what choice of $v$ you made. So a more sophisticated approach is required. Both of the answers below focus on linear dependence in $\End(V)$ rather than in $V$ itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\End}{End}$Let the dimension of $V$ be $n$. Then the dimension of $\End(V)$ is $n^2$. Hence the endomorphisms $I, A, A^2, \dots A^{n^2}$ must be linearly dependent. The coefficients of the dependence relation are the coefficients of a polynomial $f$ for which $f(A) = 0$.

As pointed out in Voldemort's answer, by the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, you can actually stop at $n$ rather than $n^2$.

Answer (score 3):

How about using the [Cayley Hamilton theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem)?